# "be something to something" meaning

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

What does "be something to something" mean? Here is an example.

> I've had two days away, I've gotten a little sleep...
> and I am finally starting to feel like myself again.
> **I think there's really something to it.**

Can you provide some examples?

example from https://www.satctranscripts.com/2010/10/sex-and-city-2-transcript-part-b.html#.X95B4dgzbZs

Comment: 'I think there's a benefit to spending time away and getting sleep'

Comment: "There's something to it" is an idiom. The problem here is that we don't have a referent for "it". It surely isn't sleep - there is nothing unusual about sleep. Please give the preceding sentence(s).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's impossible to analyse without some missing context which would tell us what "it" refers to. (Even if "it" simply refers to ***the fact of being away for two days***, that would still need to be establised by context that's not provided.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I hope you can understand that it's an example and I don't really care what it refers to. I'm asking about that structure.

Comment: Ho-hum. Well, even if *you're* not interested in what "it" means here, I went to the trouble of finding that line in your linked transcript. It's identified in the immediately preceding utterance: *[I'm sorry] For having an attitude about **that two-day idea**.* Obviously the addressee had told the speaker about some "go away for 2 days" idea (for fixing relationship problems?) which was originally rejected as ***having no merit***. But the speaker now thinks that idea has ***something to it*** (against expectations, it has at least ***some*** merit, even if it's not a complete solution).

Comment: Note that *there's **something** to it* specifically means *it has at least some truth / usefulness* - almost always with the implication that this is *against expectations*. But this is completely different to *there's **nothing** to it* - which ***doesn't*** mean *it contains no true and/or is of no use* (it means ***it's easy***).

Comment: It refers to everything getting away and getting some sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the "it" is having some effect - whether real or not - that is being perceived by the speaker but they don't know for certain.

For example:

> I've been sleeping better - there's something to these pills.

In medicine the placebo effect is where you take something, feel better, but the pill had no actual medicine in it. So maybe these pills do work, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect there to be a previous phrase or sentence, defining what "it" is, typically some principle.

> My friends say that taking a complete break will help you to recover from stress an exhaustion.

> I've had two days away, I've gotten a little sleep... and I am finally starting to feel like myself again. I think there's really something to it.

Answer (score 0):

to be something to it/that/this. where it refers to whatever came before:

- I've had two days away, I've gotten a little sleep... and I am finally starting to feel like myself again. I think there's really something to it.

it refers to being away two days and getting sleep

- I ate only salad for dinner all week and feel really great. **There's really something to that.**

it refers to eating salad for dinner all week.

- She rode her bike everyday for three weeks and lost 10 pounds. **There's really something to that.**

That refers to riding the bike and losing the weight.